# Index of a Principal ideal is the Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $d$ be a non-square integer and $\alpha$ be nonzero in
>   $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ with norm $N$, so $N = \alpha\overline{\alpha}$. 
>   Show that the principal ideal $(\alpha)$ in
>   $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ has index $|N|$.  That is, show
>   $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]/(\alpha)$ has order $|N|$.  (Hint: Consider the
>   chain of ideals $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d] \supset (\alpha) \supset (N))$.

I really don't know where to start with this one; I've never really dealt with finding order of quotient rings, although I imagine it's similar to doing so in quotient groups.  The hint makes me think of Artinian rings, but I can't see what this would have to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ideals are just subgroups. It is saying that the quotient groups $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(\alpha),\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(\overline{\alpha})$ have the same number of elements $r$ and the latter is isomorphic to $\alpha\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/\alpha(\overline{\alpha})=(\alpha)/(N)$,

since the index of subgroups satisfy $[A:C]=[A:B][B:C]$ then $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(N)$ has $r^2$ elements

On the other hand it is easy to show that $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(N)$ has $N^2$ elements

Comment: I think I get it more, and I understand your reasoning, but I'm still having trouble showing that $r = N$.

Comment: Define the elements of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(N)$ concretely, count them

Comment: It’s late at night, I’m kinda groggy, and I don’t see why $r=|N|$ either. Of course this is a standard theorem in algebraic number theory, not only for quadratic extensions…